# Custom Template for paragraph module in drupal7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-templates

Currently i am working a project in which i need to make different layout for the **paragraph** module in drupal 7. for eg: There is 3 different section layout for which i have to write the html markup and add the css according to design. In backend i have used the bundle for the paragraph and i have to print it on different position on different page which i am able to print the content using that specific template of the page. Now my problem is I am not able to figure out that where am i suppose to write the template file for the different layout of the paragraph so when ever we call it in page.tpl file it will automatically take the custom html written for the layout.tpl.

Answer (score 2):

Paragraph is an excellent choice for content building in my opinion. Good choice :)

As fas as I know paragraphs creates bundles and entities, which you can reference in your nodes or other entities, and choose it's rendering mode for every display of it's container entity.

And that means that you can do a lot of configuration, content building and theming with the awesome Display Suite (https://www.drupal.org/project/ds).

1. Download DS and learn about this awesome module (if you haven't already).
2. Optionally you can create a display for the paragraph item (http://yoursite.com/admin/structure/ds/view_modes/manage).

[image]

3. Select the displays that you want to configure (you can choose full or your new display)(http://yoursite.com/admin/structure/paragraphs/your-paragraph-entity-name/display).
   [image]
4. Configure your display, first select the template and then rearrange the fields as you like. (http://your-site.com/admin/structure/paragraphs/your-paragraph-entity-name/display/the-display-you-want-to-change)

[image]

5. Once you select a template (or design) at the bottom of the display and save it, watch the template suggestions if you want to override them (in the same path as step 4).

[image]

6. Finally in your node where the paragraph is, and inside a presentation display, full or teaser or some custom display you have, check the rendering mode for the paragraph. (http://your-site.com/admin/structure/types/manage/your-content-type/display)

[image]

Sorry if my info is messy, but there's a lot to explain. Ask me if you get lost somewhere.

Hope that helps.